# Service Fabric cluster stuck in status=Deploying

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am deploying a service fabric cluster but after the vmss nodes has come up and reported status succeeded on service fabric extension, the cluster still just waits in status = deploying.

When i remote desktop in to read the event logs I am seeing:

```
ERROR: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.AgentException: Cluster configuration is not available yet
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.<RunOnce>d__f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Let me know if I can collect any other information that help debug.

Comment: the only change I made to the default template that the azure portal creates is to remove the vhd disks and use managed disks instead

Comment: A few attempts later in the eventlog i also find: Fabric installed successfully. and then Exception occurred when invoking command: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.Utility.RunPowershellCommand(String commandText, Dictionary`2 parameters)

Comment: and then alot of Fabric host service is running is starting to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "NicPrefixOverride" like mentioned [here](https://loekd.wordpress.com/2017/02/08/running-windows-containers-on-azure-service-fabric/), paragraph 'Template'.

It will indicate the network to use when you have multiple network adapters. (The Windows Containers feature adds a network adapter)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like my problem was that when deploying to windows server 2016.

Swapping back to 2012, everything came back online.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

I saw several issues related to a **Closed Network.**(our environments limit access to the internet)  I had to look at the event logs for 1 and 2, and I had to use NetMon client for # 3.

1. nodes try to hit **download.microsoft.com:80** as part of the "software update process". fabric is uninstalled, but never re-installed. So far, had to open outbound **"23.40.68.76,23.195.64.241,23.66.100.156":80**. Will be looking to some way to re-direct these calls as we cannot do this in production.
2. Due to Self-Signed certs, need to include in the cluster template (*the portal will not accept the* **Federation:X509CertChainFlags**):

*Template Fragment:*

```
...
"fabricSettings": [
  {
    "name": "Security",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "ClusterProtectionLevel",
        "value": "[parameters('clusterProtectionLevel')]"
      },
      //https://github.com/Azure/Service-Fabric-Troubleshooting-Guides/blob/master/Security/SecurityApi_CertGetCertificateChain%20-%20CTL%20accessibility%20-%20CRL%20slow%20warnings.md
      {
        "name": "CrlCheckingFlag",
        "value": "4"
      }
    ]
  },
  //https://github.com/Azure/Service-Fabric-Troubleshooting-Guides/blob/master/Security/SecurityApi_CertGetCertificateChain%20-%20CTL%20accessibility%20-%20CRL%20slow%20warnings.md
  {
    "name": "Federation",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "X509CertChainFlags",
        "value": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

3. Event though all resources are on the same subnet, I had to open inbound ports 19000,19080 from any, due to Azure DNS server at 168.63.129.16. This is actually the [Azure Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/what-is-ip-address-168-63-129-16) and should have been in my NSG. It would have been nice if this was in the service tags.
4. I could never get cert authentication of the explorer to work, so I had to use AD Authentication. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-setup-aad

*Template Fragment:*

```
...
"azureActiveDirectory": {
  "tenantId":"<guid>",
  "clusterApplication":"<guid>",
  "clientApplication":"<guid>"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why it might happen is if you provisioned an Azure VM that does not have a temporary d:\ drive. Service Fabric uses this drive to write log files and can't start without it.

So make sure you select a VM size that has local temporary storage included.

[image]